# Does anyone know where a good resource for NFS4 ACLs can be found?

Tags: linux, nfs, access-control-list, posix

I am attempting to utilize NFS4 ACL's in an environment already utilizing POSIX ACL's.  I've found a handful of sites on the internet that explain some technical details about NFS4 ACL's and how they're created, but the tools seem to fail for me when I try to execute them.

Does anyone have a good resource/tutorial to explain how to setup NFS4 ACLs?

**When I try to change the ACL set from the server:**

```
[root@ny-bar01 foo_server]# nfs4_setfacl -e /nfs/obfuscate/
Operation to request attribute not supported.
Failed to instantiate ACL.
```

**When I try to change the ACL set from the client:**

```
[root@ny-baz02 foo_client]# nfs4_setfacl -R -e .
Failed setxattr operation: Operation not permitted
An error occurred during recursive file tree walk.
```

Comment: Do you have no_root_squash set for your nfs exports? That may cause your operation not permitted error.

Comment: Nope, root squash is enabled

Comment: Now that I reread my comment, I should've defined "that" better. Try using no_root_squash or set the ACL as a non-root user.

Comment: Thank you soo much... It really worked.. I had missed no_root_squase while exporting.. It worked finally ,, Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the record, we found out that ext4 does not natively support NFS ACL's.  There are a few filesystems with experimental NFS4 ACL support, but, experimental is not the word I want attached to my production environment.